# Trying to pull information from a table on a webpage

Tags: web-scraping, jsoup, screen-scraping, html, children

I'm fairly new with java and HTML. I've been trying to pull info from a table on a webpage for some time to no avail. From what I understand from browsing other questions, I know that I need to be using Jsoup(or something of the sorts but I'm using Jsoup) to grab the data from the website, however I get confused when it comes to "nodes" and "children" and what not in order to locate the specific information I want.

```
String margins = "https://platinumtokens.com/";

    Document doc = Jsoup.connect(margins).get();
    Elements tableElements = doc.select("div");

    System.out.println(doc);
    System.out.println(tableElements.get(0));
```

I need to save the name of the item and the prices of the items in an array or something to organize them but I'm stuck on how to pull them out of the webpage specifically.

Thanks for the help :)

EDIT: I’m not totally familiar with Java variables but I was looking to put each individual item into a list with its buy and sell price, margin, return percentage and amount traded

Comment: What is your expected output?There are several prices are there ?

Comment: I’m not totally familiar with Java variables but I was looking to put each individual item into a list with its buy and sell price, margin, return percentage and amount traded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to selenium web driver because this web page uses Javascript to display item table.
I created a test code with phantomjs.

http://www.seleniumhq.org/projects/webdriver/

http://phantomjs.org/

https://github.com/bonigarcia/webdrivermanager

```
public void test2() {

    // web driver setup
    PhantomJsDriverManager.getInstance().setup();
    PhantomJSDriver driver = new PhantomJSDriver();

    // access the web page
    driver.get("https://platinumtokens.com/");

    // wait for loading
    while (!(driver.executeScript("return document.readyState").equals("complete"))) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(500);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    // list to store item infomation
    List<Info> infos = new ArrayList<>();

    // get  tr tags
    List<WebElement> tr = driver.findElementsByTagName("tr");
    for (WebElement e: tr) {
        // get td tags inside a tr tag
        List<WebElement> td = ((RemoteWebElement) e).findElementsByTagName("td");
        if (!td.isEmpty()) {
            String name = ((RemoteWebElement) td.get(1)).findElementByTagName("a").getText();
            Info info = new Info(name, td.get(2).getText(), td.get(3).getText());
            infos.add(info);
        }
    }

    // display infomation
    for (Info info: infos) {
        System.out.println(info.toString());
    }
}

// to store a data
public static class Info {
    private String item;
    private String buy;
    private String sell;

    public Info(String item, String buy, String sell) {

        this.item = item;
        this.buy = buy;
        this.sell = sell;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Info{" +
                "item='" + item + '\'' +
                ", buy='" + buy + '\'' +
                ", sell='" + sell + '\'' +
                '}';
    }
}
```